# Run a cron job to check the due date of a task

Tags: python, django, cron, bots, chatfuel

I'm working in an integration between Django and Chatfuel.

Right now the bot is almost complete, I have difficulties with the last task, I have certain tasks to do and each them have a due time, so three days before it expires I have to send a message to my client remindering him/her that he/she have to complete this task.

I could obtain the messenger_user_id after the first interaction with my bot, now, I know i have to run a cron job at a frequent interval to check the due date and if it's close, send a message through Broadcasting API.

But I don't know how to achieve that goal.

```
    models.py 

class Tasks(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    objective = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
                default=timezone.now)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(
                default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task


views.py #in here I obtain user's fb id 

def save_fb_id(request, username, fb_id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user__username=username)
    if profile.fb_id != fb_id:
        profile.fb_id = fb_id
        profile.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: Check out [celery-beat](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov for install this is just with `pip install django-celery-beat` without install celery first?

Comment: No, this is a part of `celery` so you need to install `celery` and `celery` depends on a broker such as rabbitmq. You need to install that as well. See this: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html

Comment: Thanks @JahongirRahmonov

Answer (score 0):

You can check [django-crontab](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab) module. It is very easy to use and yet powerful in what it does.